# I cannot replace the counter 0-11 with months of the year

Tags: java, loops, counter

I want my output to show months and the sales figures but don't know what to replace what with what.

I have tried adding code to make the months appear and then the numbers to the right but I'm having no luck.

```
import java.util.Scanner;    
public class assignment2
    {

    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome!\n");
        System.out.println("Month 0 - January");
        System.out.println("Month 11 - December\n");
        System.out.println("MonthNo(year1)\tSales made\n");

        double sales[] = { 60, 54, 62, 67, 54, 67, 51, 50, 62, 55, 49, 70 };
        int sum = 0;
        int average12 = 0;

        for (int counter = 0; counter < sales.length; counter++)
            {
            sum += sales[counter];
            System.out.println(counter + "\t\t\t\t\t\t" + sales[counter]);

            }

        System.out.println("\nTotal year 1 sales " + sum + "\n");

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        System.out.println("MonthNo(year2)\tSales made\n");

        double sales2[] = { 59, 43, 48, 51, 49, 57, 39, 42, 54, 51, 60, 62 };
        int sum2 = 0;

        for (int counter = 0; counter < sales2.length; counter++)
            {
            sum2 += sales2[counter];
            System.out.println(counter + "\t\t\t\t\t\t" + sales2[counter]);
            }

        System.out.println("\nTotal year 2 sales " + sum2 + "\n");
     }

 }
```

the output -

```
Welcome!

Month 0 - January
Month 11 - December

MonthNo(year1)  Sales made

0                       60.0
1                       54.0
2                       62.0
3                       67.0
4                       54.0
5                       67.0
6                       51.0
7                       50.0
8                       62.0
9                       55.0
10                      49.0
11                      70.0

Total year 1 sales 701

MonthNo(year2)  Sales made

0                       59.0
1                       43.0
2                       48.0
3                       51.0
4                       49.0
5                       57.0
6                       39.0
7                       42.0
8                       54.0
9                       51.0
10                      60.0
11                      62.0

Total year 2 sales 615
```

Comment: Whats your actual problem? What output do you get? what output do you need?

Comment: sorry look at the edit, i think others have answered the question.

Comment: yes, i ran your code through an online compiler to fully understand. Could you choose the answer that helped you the most? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could declare a `String` array say `months` and store the names of the months in it as below:

```
String[] months = {"January", "February", .......};
```

Now in the places where used `counter` in the `System.out.println` use `months[counter]`.

This I hope will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the month numbers with the month *names* then just make an array `String months[] = {January, February, ...}` and replace

```
System.out.println(counter + "\t\t\t\t\t\t" + sales[counter]);
```

with

```
System.out.println(months[counter] + "\t\t\t\t\t\t" + sales[counter]);
```

You should also replace this piece of code in your second for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Add this import statement:
import java.text.DateFormatSymbols;

And Change the code:

```
String monthString;
for (int counter = 0; counter < sales.length; counter++)
{
        sum += sales[counter];
        monthString = new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[counter];
        System.out.println(monthString + "\t\t\t\t\t\t" + sales[counter]);
}
```